# Break down python process

Tags: python, apriori

I want to try to breakdown some line code from apriori algorithm i downloaded from [apriori using python](https://github.com/asaini/Apriori) because it will gives my memory error when i try to compute huge dataset. 
here is some problem i just found.

```
def joinSet(itemSet, length):
        """Join a set with itself and returns the n-element itemsets"""
        return set([i.union(j) for i in itemSet for j in itemSet if len(i.union(j)) == length])
```

I want to know actual size of return var when error triggered, so i try to breakdown those code to be this.

```
def joinSet(itemSet, length):
    """Join a set with itself and returns the n-element itemsets"""
    ret = []
    for i in itemSet:
        for j in itemSet:
            if len(i.union(j)) == length:
                ret.append(i.union(j))
    return ret
```

so i can monitor every step, but my breakdown code doesn't gives the same result with original one.

What do i miss anyway?
And also i will very appreciate if you can gives me actual solution if my approaches goes wrong way.
Thankyou.

Comment: Try just removing the `[]` inside set. That creates a list unnecessarily, because it's immediately discarded by turning it into a set. If it's available, I'd also create a bug report or pull request to the original source, because that's an optimization that has no downside that I can see.

Comment: Yeh, in the first code segment the list is converted to a set before you return it. In the second code segment you just return the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be that the original returns a set, and you are returning a list.

```
def joinSet(itemSet, length):
    """Join a set with itself and returns the n-element itemsets"""
    ret = []
    for i in itemSet:
        for j in itemSet:
            if len(i.union(j)) == length:
                ret.append(i.union(j))
    return set(ret)
```

Also I think you can save a considerable amount of memory with the following edit of the original:

```
def joinSet(itemSet, length):
        """Join a set with itself and returns the n-element itemsets"""
        return {i.union(j) for i in itemSet for j in itemSet if len(i.union(j)) == length}
```

This is a set comprehension requires python >= 2.7

Comment: thankyou, the first one works for me,.
ill try to apply second option and will report soon,..